# Use Windows 8 installer (EXE) on a OS free (only DOS) laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-installation

Good morning,

I just found a sweet deal for a Lenovo Y510P (Intel Core i7 4700MQ, 16GB di RAM, SSD da 256GB, NVIDIA GeForce GT 755m / 2 GB, DOS), that is shipped with only DOS installed. 
Since I'm an academic employee I would like to make use of the "Student" discount on the Microsoft Store, in order to buy Windows 8.1 Pro Student at 59euros (btw, is this edition different from the stsandard Windows 8.1 Pro edition?).
My question is: the purchase consists in a .exe file; will I be able to install it on that laptop? And how?

Comment: I'll wait until I receive the laptop, because I already have a spare unused copy of Windows 8 (from a previous laptop). Otherwise I'll follow your instructions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best ideal practice would be to burn the content of your windows 8 files which you purchased which should include more than a .exe file, but also the boot files along with some extra content so it should look like this

[image]

This content as mentioned should either be burned onto a USB stick which can be done following these instructions

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

So now you have a copy of the OS which you can use to repair or reinstall your OS if needed. As for the differences with this student version, it just simply is cheaper for students but you need to prove you are a student.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between student edition and the standard edition, except the price and the product key time period. As of the student edition usually has from 2 to 5 years before its expired, while you can use the standard product key as long as you have it with you.

Is the Windows compressed in EXE file ? or the company gives you an EXE file as gateway to download and install windows ? 
both cases are different, because some companies force the users to download the files using some sort of gateway programs to secured their server contents. 
(it's more like the most programs installer these days e.g Skype, Google Chrome..etc), so if is it a gateway EXE to download the Windows ISO, then you Have to get that ISO and burn it (On a DVD or USB). You can verify that by the file size (the original size of the Windows 8 will be more than 3GB), if is it less than 20MB, then it's a gateway.

If you confirmed that the EXE file is a FULL Windows 8 Installer, and it's bootable file (LIKE THE ISO BUT Different file source) **THEN** you just need to create bootable FreeDOS flash drive and run the file from it, and to do that **JUST DO THE FOLLOWING :**

**[HOW TO] Create A Bootable FreeDOS USB Using Rufus :**

[What you NEED]

- A copy of Rufus ([CLICK HERE](http://rufus.akeo.ie/downloads/rufus-1.4.10.exe) to download) [Freeware]
- A USB Flash Drive larger than 4 GB.

[Work Flow]

1. Plugin your USB Flash Drive, then open Refus
2. Open *Refus*
3. On the **Format Options** section, tick on :

   - **Quick Format**
   - **Create a bootable disk using** (choose from the drop down menu **FreeDOS**).

See Picture :

[image]

4. Click on **Start** and wait until it's finished.

After you're done from the above steps, your flash drive is ready for the next step.

Copy the Windows 8.1 Pro EXE file that you downloaded, then go to your bootable flash drive, you'll see some files inside the flash drive already there, just paste the EXE file in your flash drive root directory, and rename it to **setup**. Now, you're ready to use the flash drive to install Windows on the new laptop.

**To install the Windows on the new laptop:**

1. Plugin the bootable flash drive that you've just created.
2. Turn on your new laptop and press **F12** until the *boot menu options* shows up.
3. From the *boot menu options*, choose *your USB flash drive* and hit **Enter**.
4. The FreeDOS should show up, and you'll able to type DOS commands on the screen.
5. Type **setup.exe** then hit **Enter**.
6. The Windows 8 installer will show up.

Now, you're inside the system installer, and you can just follow the installer screens to install it.

Comment: > Is the Windows compressed in EXE file ? or the company gives you an EXE file as gateway to download and install windows ?

I don't know what will I really buy, but in this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nqpj937i51p0b1/Screenshot%202014-10-07%2013.12.18.png?dl=0 it says "download exe file".

Comment: This is Microsoft Store download tool, which will download the Windows first, then It'll give you three options "(install now, install later by creating media, and install later from your desktop) you should choose "Install by creating media" and click next, then choose "ISO file" and you will need to provide a save location, then Setup will copy the ISO to that location. Click Finish to close Setup. Now, you'll have the FULL Windows 8.1 Pro ISO file, all you have to do is burn it on a USB or DVD. You can use Refus to burn it on USB flash drive.